# Finding the joint density function of $(X+Y,X)$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent and following an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda>0$

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ that both follow an exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda > 0$, I am trying to find the joint density function of $(X+Y,X)$.

I have managed to prove that the density function of $X+Y$ is the density function of a $\Gamma(2,\lambda)$ distribution but I am struggling to find the joint density function of $(X+Y,X)$. I have tried to find its distribution function in order to calculate the derivative, but I have not succeeded.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Hint: begin after first noting that the support of the joint pdf is the second octant and not the first quadrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach. We will assume $a \geq b \geq 0$. First condition over the value of $X$:
$$P(X+Y \leq a, X \leq b) = \int_{-\infty}^{b}P(X+Y \leq a|X=x)f_X(x) dx$$
Then use the density function of $X$ and the fact $X$ and $Y$ are independent
$$=\int_{0}^{b}P(x+Y \leq a)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=\int_{0}^{b}P(Y \leq a-x)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{b}(1-e^{-\lambda (a-x)})\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=\lambda \int_{0}^{b} e^{-\lambda x} - e^{-\lambda (a-x)-\lambda x}dx$$
$$=\lambda((\frac{e^{-\lambda b}}{-\lambda} - \frac{e^{0}}{-\lambda})-e^{-\lambda a}(b-0)) = 1-e^{-\lambda b}-b\lambda e^{-\lambda a}$$
Now to find the joint density we need
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b} (1-e^{-\lambda b}-b\lambda e^{-\lambda a}) = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda a}.$$
Now note if $a < b$, $\{X+Y \leq a, X \leq b\} \implies Y<0$, and so
$$P(X+Y \leq a, X \leq b)=0$$
And also if $b<0$,
$$P(X \leq b)=0$$
Combining this all together yields
$$f_{X+Y,X}(a,b) = \begin{cases}
\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda a} & a \geq b \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's crystal clear now !

Comment: Unless you include indicator functions, or otherwise describe the _support_ of the joint pdf, your answer is wrong.  -1 pending appropriate edits.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you are correct, I've edited now.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed my downvote.